# What happens exactly when a file is opened in read mode in python

Tags: python, linux, file

- I have one file `test.txt`
- I opened it in python in read mode `fp = open('test.txt', 'r')`
- Now I deleted that file from hard disk ($ rm test.txt)
- Now If I say `fp.read()` I am getting all the content from the file

But What I know is when we create file object, the file won't load into RAM. Then if I delete it from hard disk, then from where I am accessing the file content?

Comment: My guess is that the OS you are using greedily reads the file into RAM and is available when `fp.read()` is called. Or it could be python that reads the file contents anyway.

Comment: Deleting a file often doesn't really delete it -- it just marks it as deleted. The bytes are left in place undisturbed (until another file overwrites it). What you are seeing might just be undefined behavior. It typically works that way but isn't guaranteed. Reading the source could shed more light on the situation.

Comment: @quamrana I am using Ubuntu. Even when I create a file-object for large files and see RAM usage (htop) there is no difference.

Comment: Deleting a file usually doesn't remove the data but removed the information about the existance of the file. If the object has a pointer to the address of the data, it can happily read the data anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The details might depend on the OS you're using, but for Linux you're talking about, the more appropriate question on how is this possible would not be how did the file get opened, but what happens when the file is being deleted. Answer to which you can find in the description of `unlink(2)` syscall:

```
...
   unlink() deletes a name from the filesystem.  If that name was the last
   link to a file and no processes have the file open, the file is deleted
   and the space it was using is made available for reuse.

   If  the  name  was the last link to a file but any processes still have
   the file open, the file will remain in existence until  the  last  file
   descriptor referring to it is closed.
...
```

If you look at it from the the python perspective, the file may no longer have a name in the file system, but it's still there and you can also do the following:

```
>>> f = open('TEST')
>>> os.unlink('TEST')
>>> print(os.fstat(f.fileno()))
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=146934248, st_dev=2431, st_nlink=0, st_uid=1000, st_gid=100, st_size=5, st_atime=1517409090, st_mtime=1517409090, st_ctime=1517409124)
```